# angular ngCookies Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

In my angular app I installed angular-cookies => npm install angular-cookies.

I add the following to my angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies','ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies) {
```

I get the following error when I try to launch:

Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)
    at https://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.min.js:6:417 ......

I am not sure why my injection is failing

Comment: Do you load or require the script?

Comment: In my html I have the following:  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Link 404s for me :)

Comment: here is entire error message from chrome - angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…0(https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjavascripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A153)(…)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4117s @ angular.js:323g @ angular.js:4078Ob @ angular.js:4004d @ angular.js:1446sc @ angular.js:1467Jd @ angular.js:1361(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26111a @ angular.js:2741c @ angular.js:3011

Comment: when I click in the link I see:  errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/nomod?p0=ngCookies

Comment: Here is the entire error message: errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A %5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.11%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngCookies%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.11%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngCookies%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fjavascripts%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A417%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fjavascripts%252Fangular.min.js

Comment: please check you can access //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular‌​-cookies.js  @qqilihq and me not able to access it and we are getting 404. And if that script is not available then you will get mentioned error

Comment: Here is one sample http://plnkr.co/edit/1GvNapYdl5gVaa18HZgQ?p=preview you check what is missing in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem this morning,

Try to get the same api version of angular and angular-cookies, your angular version is 1.3.11 and your angular-cookies is 1.4.4.

This [link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/) is the latest stable version of all components (1.5.8)

A part of my app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);

app.controller('loginFormController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http','$cookies', function($scope, $log, $http, $cookies) {
//Your code here
}]);
```

A part of my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>App| Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/login.css">
        <script src="../assets/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../controller/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="loginFormController as login">
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  Using all the same version is definitely something I needed to do.  Unfortunately I am still getting the the error (due to character limit, I had to remove some of the error link).  I will keep looking. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngCookies&p1=Error
%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org
%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DngCookies%0A%20%20%20%20at%20
https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjavascripts%2Fangular.min.js
%3A6%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have been out.  It turns out I had not put the following into my html     <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>.  That coupled with your suggestion, I was able to get it to work.  Thanks again.